# Create collection of objects then lookup match in collection in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a hard time with this specific issue because these are 2-3 new concepts I'm working with at once.  I'm new to collections and classes, having only done dynamic arrays in the past (yes, I know, lots of "Redim Preserves").  This has sufficed before, but I'm finally at the point where I need something more powerful to handle my lists.

To setup, I need to create a dynamic list of named dynamic lists, then read them out in order.

Example:
Imagine a spreadsheet of sandwich ingredients, where Column A is Ingredient and Column B is Sandwich Name.  (The number of sandwiches and the number of ingredients in each sandwich is unknown, thus all the dynamic-ness.)

I need to go down the rows and read the sandwich type.
If there is a sandwich of that name already, add the ingredient to the end of that sandwich's list. If not, make a new list.

At the End of it, go through the sandwiches and print out each one's list of ingredients.

I think I need to make a "Sandwiches" collection of "Sandwich" objects and I've gotten as far as starting a "CSandwich" class, with "Public property get Name() as string". But then I got lost on how to make a the Ingredients array or even what data-type to use...

Thanks

Comment: VBA is quite a primitive language. What exactly do you need to do with the data? Sounds like more a project for Access or some other SQL query based system.

Comment: While I agree with you, I must also add that this is a tack-on to a much larger project already started and written in VBA. (You should've seen it before I got my hands on it.)

I'll eventually get around to rewriting it in something more powerful, but as it stands, this is what I got to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with clum.  VBA is very convenient for many tasks but it is not suited for every task.  Personally I find its handling of classes very clumsy.

The code below does what you seek with Collections but without Classes.  Experiment with collections now and once you feel comfortable with them consider studying classes.  You may also wish to investigate Dictionaries which are similar to Collections and may be more appropriate for your current requirement.

To test and demonstrate my routine, I created a worksheet containing:

[image: Sample data]

As I typed, this I reread your question.  I see I have the columns reversed but I have decided not to fix that.

Sub `RecordSandI` reads each row and calls `AddSandI` to store the contents of the row as appropriate.  It then outputs the contents of collection `Sandwich` to give:

```
Sandwich a has ingredients:  1  2  3
Sandwich b has ingredients:  3  4
Sandwich c has ingredients:  1  5  6
Sandwich d has ingredients:  2
```

`Sandwich` is a collection of collections.  For each sub-collection, the first element is the sandwich name and the remaining elements are the ingredients.

As I suggest earlier, see how far you can take this approach before trying anything more complicated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RecordSandI()

  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim Sandwich As New Collection

  With Worksheets("SandI")
    RowCrnt = 2

    Do While .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value <> ""
      Call AddSandI(Sandwich, .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value, .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value)
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
    Loop

  End With

  For InxS = 1 To Sandwich.Count
    Debug.Print "Sandwich " & Sandwich(InxS)(1) & " has ingredients:";
    For InxI = 2 To Sandwich(InxS).Count
      Debug.Print "  " & Sandwich(InxS)(InxI);
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

End Sub
Sub AddSandI(ByRef Sandwich As Collection, ByVal SandwichName As String, ByVal IngredientName As String)

  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim SandwichNew As Collection

  For InxS = 1 To Sandwich.Count
    If Sandwich(InxS)(1) = SandwichName Then
      ' This sandwich already recorded
      For InxI = 2 To Sandwich(InxS).Count
        If Sandwich(InxS)(InxI) = IngredientName Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Ingredient already recorded
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Next
      ' New ingredient
      Sandwich(InxS).Add IngredientName
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next

  ' New sandwich
  Set SandwichNew = New Collection
  SandwichNew.Add SandwichName
  SandwichNew.Add IngredientName
  Sandwich.Add SandwichNew

End Sub
```

Comment: Is "Inx" an increment counter?  with 'InxS' and 'InxI' for Increment Sandwich and Increment Ingredient respectively?

Comment: @JosephLopez. I have a naming convention that I have used for years which means I can look at macros I wrote in 2005 and know what all the variables are.  Very helpful when updating an old macro. `Sandwich` is an exception but most of my variable names are a sequence of words.

Comment: The first word tells when I am using the variable for; each subsequent word narrows down the scope until the name is unique.  "Inx" tells you it is an index for an 1D array or a collection. "Row" tells you it is a row of a worksheet or a 2D array. "I" is short for ingredient and "S" for Sandwich" (as you guessed) and tells you what they are indices for.